# issue in magento 2.2.8 send multiple attachment in single mail

Tags: magento2.2.8, attachment, multiple-file-upload

I have installed https://github.com/manishjoy1993/email-attachment extesnion in my magento 2.2.8 version. Everthing is fine but I can not send multiple attachment in single mail. For multiple attachments I have created 2 functions
in controller

```
->addAttachment(self::TEST_FILE_CONTENT, self::TEST_FILE_NAME, self::TEST_FILE_TYPE)
->addAttachment1(self::TEST_FILE_CONTENT, self::TEST_FILE_NAME, self::TEST_FILE_TYPE)
```

If I pass only one addAttachment() function,so I am receiving pdf file perfectly if I attach 2 pdf file in two different function so I  am getting this kind of mail
 [image]

here is my code in Controller file

```
<?php


namespace Excellence\EmailAttachment\Controller\Index;

use Excellence\EmailAttachment\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**@#+
     * Test Data.
     */
    const TEST_TEMPLATE_IDENTIFIER = 'excellence_test_attachment';
    const TEST_FROM_EMAIL = 'general';
    const TEST_TO_EMAIL = 'to@gmail.com';
    const TEST_FILE_CONTENT = 'Test file content.';
    const TEST_FILE_NAME = 'test12.pdf';
    const TEST_FILE_TYPE = 'application/pdf';
    /**@#-*/

    /**
     * @var \Excellence\EmailAttachment\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
     */
    protected $state;

    /**
     * TestAttachment constructor.
     *
     * @param \Excellence\EmailAttachment\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
     * @param null $name
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder, State $state)
    {
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->state = $state;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            // $this->state->setAreaCode(Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
            $sender = [
                                    'email' => 'aaaa@gmail.com',
                                    'name' => 'aaaaa'

                                ];
            $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier(self::TEST_TEMPLATE_IDENTIFIER)
                ->setTemplateOptions([
                                        'area' => 'frontend',
                                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                                    ])
                ->setTemplateVars([])
                ->addAttachment(self::TEST_FILE_CONTENT, self::TEST_FILE_NAME, self::TEST_FILE_TYPE)
                ->addAttachment1(self::TEST_FILE_CONTENT, self::TEST_FILE_NAME, self::TEST_FILE_TYPE)
                ->setFrom($sender )
                ->addTo(self::TEST_TO_EMAIL)
                ->getTransport()
                ->sendMessage();

            print_r(__('Everything is fine, email has been sent.'));
        } catch (MailException $me) {
            print_r(__('MailException: %1', $me->getMessage()));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            print_r(__('Exception: %1', $e->getMessage()));
        }
    } 
}
```

Here is **app\code\Excellence\EmailAttachment\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder.php** file

```
<?php

namespace Excellence\EmailAttachment\Mail\Template;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{

    public function addAttachment($content, $fileName, $fileType)
    {
        $this->message->setBodyAttachment($content, $fileName, $fileType);

        return $this;
    }
    public function addAttachment1($content, $fileName, $fileType)
    {
        $this->message->setBodyAttachment($content, $fileName, $fileType);

        return $this;
    }

   protected function prepareMessage()
    {
        parent::prepareMessage();

        $this->message->setPartsToBody();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**app\code\Excellence\EmailAttachment\Mail\Message.php** file

```
<?php


namespace Excellence\EmailAttachment\Mail;

use Zend\Mime\Mime;
use Zend\Mime\PartFactory;
use Zend\Mail\MessageFactory as MailMessageFactory;
use Zend\Mime\MessageFactory as MimeMessageFactory;

class Message extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Message implements \Magento\Framework\Mail\MailMessageInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Zend\Mime\PartFactory
     */
    protected $partFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Zend\Mime\MessageFactory
     */
    protected $mimeMessageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Zend\Mail\Message
     */
    private $zendMessage;

    /**
     * @var \Zend\Mime\Part[]
     */
    protected $parts = [];


    public function __construct(PartFactory $partFactory, MimeMessageFactory $mimeMessageFactory, $charset = 'utf-8')
    {
        $this->partFactory = $partFactory;
        $this->mimeMessageFactory = $mimeMessageFactory;
        $this->zendMessage = MailMessageFactory::getInstance();
        $this->zendMessage->setEncoding($charset);
    }

    public function setBodyText($content)
    {
        $textPart = $this->partFactory->create();

        $textPart->setContent($content)
            ->setType(Mime::TYPE_TEXT)
            ->setCharset($this->zendMessage->getEncoding());

        $this->parts[] = $textPart;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setBodyHtml($content)
    {
        $htmlPart = $this->partFactory->create();

        $htmlPart->setContent($content)
            ->setType(Mime::TYPE_HTML)
            ->setCharset($this->zendMessage->getEncoding());

        $this->parts[] = $htmlPart;

        return $this;
    }


    public function setBodyAttachment($content, $fileName, $fileType)
    {
        $attachmentPart = $this->partFactory->create();

        $attachmentPart->setContent($content)
            ->setType($fileType)
            ->setFileName($fileName)
            ->setDisposition(Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT)
            ->setEncoding(Mime::ENCODING_BASE64);

        $this->parts[] = $attachmentPart;

        return $this;
    }


    public function setPartsToBody()
    {
        $mimeMessage = $this->mimeMessageFactory->create();
        $mimeMessage->setParts($this->parts);
        $this->zendMessage->setBody($mimeMessage);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setBody($body)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setSubject($subject)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->setSubject($subject);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSubject()
    {
        return $this->zendMessage->getSubject();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->zendMessage->getBody();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setFrom($fromAddress)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->setFrom($fromAddress);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function addTo($toAddress)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->addTo($toAddress);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function addCc($ccAddress)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->addCc($ccAddress);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function addBcc($bccAddress)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->addBcc($bccAddress);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setReplyTo($replyToAddress)
    {
        $this->zendMessage->setReplyTo($replyToAddress);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getRawMessage()
    {
        return $this->zendMessage->toString();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function setMessageType($type)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi bro try like this..

**TransportBuilder**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Mail\Template;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\FactoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\SenderResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Zend\Mime\Mime;
use Zend\Mime\Part as MimePart;
use Zend\Mime\PartFactory as MimePartFactory;
use Zend\Mime\Message as MimeMessage;
use Zend\Mime\MessageFactory as MimeMessageFactory;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
/** @var MimePart[] */
private $parts = [];

/** @var MimeMessageFactory */
private $mimeMessageFactory;

/** @var MimePartFactory */
private $mimePartFactory;

public function __construct(
    FactoryInterface $templateFactory,
    MessageInterface $message,
    SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver,
    ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    TransportInterfaceFactory $mailTransportFactory,
    MimePartFactory $mimePartFactory,
    MimeMessageFactory $mimeMessageFactory,
    MessageInterfaceFactory $messageFactory = null
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $templateFactory,
        $message,
        $senderResolver,
        $objectManager,
        $mailTransportFactory,
        $messageFactory
    );

    $this->mimePartFactory    = $mimePartFactory;
    $this->mimeMessageFactory = $mimeMessageFactory;
}

protected function prepareMessage()
{
    parent::prepareMessage();

    $mimeMessage = $this->getMimeMessage($this->message);

    foreach ($this->parts as $part) {
        $mimeMessage->addPart($part);
    }

    $this->message->setBody($mimeMessage);

    return $this;
}

public function addAttachment(
    $filename = null,
    $body,
    $mimeType = Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
    $disposition = Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    $encoding = Mime::ENCODING_BASE64
) {
    $this->parts[] = $this->createMimePart($filename, $body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding);
    return $this;
}

private function createMimePart(
    $filename = null,
    $content,
    $type = Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
    $disposition = Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    $encoding = Mime::ENCODING_BASE64
) {
    /** @var MimePart $mimePart */
    $mimePart = $this->mimePartFactory->create(['content' => $content]);
    $mimePart->setType($type);
    $mimePart->setDisposition($disposition);
    $mimePart->setEncoding($encoding);

    if ($filename) {
        $mimePart->setFileName($filename);
    }

    return $mimePart;
}

private function getMimeMessage(MessageInterface $message)
{
    $body = $message->getBody();

    if ($body instanceof MimeMessage) {
        return $body;
    }

    /** @var MimeMessage $mimeMessage */
    $mimeMessage = $this->mimeMessageFactory->create();

    if ($body) {
        $mimePart = $this->createMimePart((string)$body, Mime::TYPE_TEXT, Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE);
        $mimeMessage->setParts([$mimePart]);
    }

    return $mimeMessage;
}
```

> Create a preference for **Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder.php** and than test in your custom controller with the multiple addAttachment() method. It should work. It worked for me.