# Magento 2 Add attachment in email not working for multiple store

Tags: magento2, order-email, attachment

I am trying to send an attachment with Order success email.
I have 2 store **default** and **custom**. In **default** store attachment is working perfectly but in **custom** store. Email not sent.

After debugging I found a line where email stop working:

```
$this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
```

Under `drawItem` function code is:

```
protected function _drawItem(
        \Magento\Framework\DataObject $item,
        \Zend_Pdf_Page $page,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
    ) {
        $type = $item->getOrderItem()->getProductType();
        $renderer = $this->_getRenderer($type);
        $renderer->setOrder($order);
        $renderer->setItem($item);
        $renderer->setPdf($this);
        $renderer->setPage($page);
        $renderer->setRenderedModel($this);

        $renderer->draw();

        return $renderer->getPage();
    }
```

in this file, execution stops after this the following line:-

```
$renderer->draw();
```

Please tell me how to send attachment with email in multiple stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use the following module to add email attachment to an order

> https://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-email-attachments-m2.html

Comment: I used it. But it's not working for multiple store.

Answer (score 1):

which version of Magento are you using. I ran into issues with Magento 2.3 when I was not able to send any attachment. Please check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286732/issue-in-magento-2-2-8-send-multiple-attachment-in-single-mail/289843#289843) to add an attachment to your email.

I would also suggest you to try the [Mpdf](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) library to generate pdf files. It is very easy to use. You can generate your Html using a custom **block->to_html()** and pass the HTML to Mpdf **output()**. It will create the file. And after that add the pdf file path to the addAttachment().

URL: [issue in magento 2.2.8 send multiple attachment in single mail](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286732/issue-in-magento-2-2-8-send-multiple-attachment-in-single-mail/289843#289843)

I hope it helps!